# Cannot Login to 14.10 GUI

Tags: login, gui, 14.10

I cannot login my GUI login in 14.10

guest login works
boot in recovery mode and change user password with success

reboot and cannot get past GUI login -- it takes password then it acts like its going to the desktop then it goes back to GUI login

I can login in recovery mode with this user name just fine so I know the password is good

Please Help  --- I really don't want to reinstall

Comment: Did this happens after a kernel update? What GPU do you have? Dit you installed drivers from a ppa? Are their any "grapical" glitches, like resolution that looks strange?

Comment: I did a kernel update days ago without problems

Comment: no resolution change and Im not sure what gpu I have

Comment: I Did NOT install any new drivers

Comment: I can GRUB back to aprevious kernel nut that did not work

Comment: did a system reinstall and still have the GUI login problem but now guest login will not connect to my wifi

Comment: Ehm, I am afraid I don't know how to solve this problem than ;-;. Normally all login gui problems I have are caused because of the GPU drivers need the linux-headers in order to get loaded. meaby you could try to install these (use the TTY1 with ctrl+alt+f1).

Comment: Same here. Let me know if you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is something to do with an xorg lock file called .Xauthority that is stored in the user's home directory. Just log in via the terminal and then delete the lock file(s) (there were two in my case).

I think the problem arises when xorg does not close properly. You can check my other answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/633432/417772)