# Can't login on the GUI!

Tags: login, 14.10

I am unable to login to Ubuntu in the GUI interface using my username. It keeps returning to the login page once I enter the password. I can however login as a guest.

I had just manually installed Ubuntu 14.10 with a 500mb partition for `/boot`, a 2gb partition for swap, a 30gb partition for `/`, 50mb for EFI as a logical partition, 100gb for `/home` and 3 other logical partitions of 100 GB each which were given `/d`, `/e` and `/f` mount points respectively. If otherwise unspecified, all partitions were primary.

Device for installing Ubuntu was the entire hard disk.

I had to specify that at boot up that the EFI was to be turned off.

I could login normally after that. I then turned on the options for `automatically mount` for each of the 100gb hard disk partitions. I restarted my laptop after that and now I am unable to login.

Please help!

Comment: Can you login to TTY1?

Comment: Same here. I can login using TTY1, but the GUI keeps throwing me back to the login screen when I enter the correct password. If entering the wrong password it still notifies about it. No idea what to do. The issue started after the OS was installed for two months.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in another distro based on ubuntu (elementaty OS). Turns out it was caused by an .Xauthority lock file that was not deleted when I did an unsafe shutdown. You can see the problem if you go to tty and try to startx, the error says it times out while waiting for the lock.

To resolve the problem I logged in to terminal `Ctrl + Alt + F1` and navigated to my home folder and deleted the `.Xauthority` files.

When I returned to GUI `Ctrl + Alt + F7`, I was able to log in successfully