# Connected to wifi but no internet access in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, adapter

[image: list of drivers][image: List of Drivers Installed][image: Network Manager Status]

[image: iwconfig]

And lastly I would like to say that I have noticed that internet works just fine when I login in single user mode(recovery) but in tty and console it doesn't!
I tried the solution mentioned in this question also but it didn't work
[Cannot Login to 14.10 GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563944/cannot-login-to-14-10-gui)

PS Sorry but, I am on my phone and I cannot type out all the output and I couldn't take screenshots so using images please help!

Comment: can you ping `ping -c 3 google.com` ?

Comment: @kenn it displays `Temporary Failure in name resolution`

Comment: Try doing a `dmesg | grep -i rtl8111` or substitute **realtek** or whatever other name or serial matches your network card. It should show an error and if you post that, the community might be able to help.

Comment: you can temporarily disable your firewall and give it a try: `sudo ufw disabe`. Don't forget to reanable it subsequently `sudo ufw enable`

Answer (score 0):

This may be a late reply, but have you tried adding nameservers manually
I had the same issue when installing Docker and I solved it by adding editing resolv.conf file and adding the following nameservers manually.

`sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

add

`nameserver 8.8.8.8`
`nameserver 8.8.4.4`